# Android setText and getText in fragment

Tags: android, fragment

When I clicked on a button on ActionBar I can `getText()` from `editText` but `onCreate` activity when I try to `setText` to `editText` the app crashed. The problem is that editText returns null.

Edited:

```
public class TransactionAdd extends FragmentActivity...

EditText editText;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_transactions_pager);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        editText = (EditText) mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editText.setText("TEST"); // ...when I test this one, it works
            }
        });
        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        editText.setText("TEST"); // ...this one does not
```

Comment: You probably call `findViewById` before `setContentView()`

Comment: No I do not call it before `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a reference of the EditText in the OnCreateView method of your fragment.

An example:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    yourEditTextVariable = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.yourId);
    return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I do not need it in Fragment. I need to set it on activity.